# cannot get string.setfont() method working

Tags: android, string

I am using

```
String str;
tFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/custom.ttf");
str.setFont(tFace);
```

in android.. It is coming up as `Cannot resolve method 'setFont(android.graphics.TypeFace)'`

log cat shows:
Error:(137, 24) error: cannot find symbol method setFont(Typeface)

using str.setTypeface(tFace); comes up with the same error..

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using it on a String or TextView

Comment: I am using it on a String

Comment: Example of use: 
        Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Roboto regular", R.raw.roboto_regular);

        button.setTypeface(tf);  textView.setTypeface(tf);

Comment: What's the [documentation for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) say? Nothing, right?

Comment: String are not meant to be shown, while EditText or TextView are. Font is handled for them, not for String.

Answer (score 1):

`setFont()` simply does not exists.

Use [setTypeface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29)

Answer (score 1):

You use setTypeFace to set a font on a TextView or EditTextView.  A string in Android has no such methods and they all merely operate on character strings and do not have methods varying how those strings are represented visually